# Binding color to Solidbrush.color in c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, viewport3d

I have a class Cell looking something like this:

```
public Color color{get { return colorr; }
set { colorr = value;
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null){
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("color"));
        }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Im adding a lot of "cell"'s to a viewport3D for generating cubes. And the colors of the cells change as time goes. So my question is - instead of redrawing the cells everytime they change, can I bind a cell's color to a solidbrush in code?

I have something like this, but it wont work.

```
Binding b = new Binding();
        b.Source = cell.color;

        SolidColorBrush solidBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(solidBrush, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, b);

        Material material = new DiffuseMaterial(solidBrush);
```

I would suppose now that the color of the solidBrush would change when the cell's color changes, and therefore the color of the cube on the viewport3D changes. But it doesnt.

Thanks
- David

Comment: How about properly formatting code before posting it? (Note: The current state does *not* satisfy that property)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [how to debug bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

There are no binding updates to changes of the `Source`, if you want updates you need to set a `Path` relative to a source. e.g.

```
b.Source = cell;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("color");
```

This is because the binding will subscribe to [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on the source (and non-leaves on the path) and check if the name reported by the event matches the path, if so the target is updated.